# Emacs as the latex editor

Tags: emacs

I am using Emacs for editing my latex document. Is there any way to make Emacs as WYSIWYG editor so that the editing will be easier. I need to reduce the number of time I compile the document also. I was using Texmaker before for editing the documents but I find Emacs more powerful. In texmaker, I need to compile every time to see the output. This is also same for Emacs in tex mode also.

I use Xelatex for compilation on Ubuntu 12.04. I am expecting a package like 
Lyx.
I am not asking for a complete WYSIWYG editor - I rephrase my question to 
HOw can I change Emacs as an editor that can show the alignments of margins, displaying text in prescribed fonts, and overall layout without compilation. Together with the text handling capability of Emacs.

Comment: Do you already use [AucTeX](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/)? By the way, why did you add the `xetex` tab? Are you only using XeTeX?

Comment: @ph0t0nix Is it WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: Did you click the link? The first line on the page says "AUCTeX is an extensible package for writing and formatting TeX files in GNU Emacs".  A bit further down it says: "AUCTeX includes preview-latex which makes LaTeX a tightly integrated component of your editing workflow by visualizing selected source chunks (such as single formulas or graphics) directly as images in the source buffer.".

Comment: I think that the best you get is incremental updates using _WhizzyTeX_ https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhizzyTeX However--"WhizzyTeX is still under development and may contain dangerous bugs. You may wish to save copies of the file (and of the whole directory you are working in) before WhizzyTeX-ing." _Bakoma_ is the only true WYSIWYG editor, https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiWs-iSmvrMAhUM4SYKHVDZAE4QFggoMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bakoma-tex.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNG25ZBbmO1ifDLtsLpVuatZOm4VUQ&sig2=DW4hD_DSkzSFSBBqZ46n6w

Comment: This is generally the same for all editors, though some (e.g. Gummi) will/can compile continuously. LyX does something different. But you don't have to compile every time you write a new sentence of course.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have lots of non Latin scripts, it makes the compiler to forget about spacing.

Comment: However, _Bakoma_, if I am not mistaken, limits you to LaTeX only.

Comment: use org-mode http://orgmode.org/; some swear by it

Comment: I just use `latexmk` running in continuous preview mode, then I just have to save the file, the rest is compiled automatically. Of course I loose ``C-c ` `` but for me that has not been that big a deal when I can still use the power full editing tools. I use Evince as preview (with inverse search enabled). If the project is large, then using `\include` and `\includeonly` to limit what is being compiles increases the compilation speed. (Note Hadn't seen that Keks had already mentioned `latexmk`, though I've never used PDF-tools)

Answer (score 4):

There is no real WYSIWYG possible with LaTeX, because the editor needs to display the commands, sections, environments, whatever.

But there are several steps to provide a clean look on your text and have a real fast compilation.

1. C-o C-b C-t (as far as I remember) hides most of the commands in Emacs.
2. Install and use [PDF-Tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) for viewing the PDF, very fast.
3. Open the shell of Emacs (`M-x eshell`) and start »latexmk«, which will compile your *.tex file every time you save it.
4. Use automatic saving:

   (require 'auto-save-buffers)
   (run-with-idle-timer 2 t 'auto-save-buffers)
   (global-set-key [f8] 'auto-save-buffers-toggle)
5. If you are really done with the preamble, you can even build your own format and use it, it will accelerate compiling very much.

Comment: I don't need a complete WYSIWYG editor. I need features like I can see the margins and formatting , fonts, alignment, adding tables  etc..

Comment: Then PDF-Tools,  latexmk and especially a feature called synctex are your friends.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? I need to know how it looks like

Comment: You mean `C-c C-o C-b`, after `tex-fold-mode` has been activated.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you trying `spacemacs` and it's `Latex layer`. It offers a 0 configuration way to use latex with emacs. Live preview is also provided by `Preview Latex` package. If you love both latex and emacs, spacemacs will amaze you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got a solution
GNU TeXmacs Editor. I installed it from  Ubuntu Software center.

```
http://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/home/welcome.en.html
```

Comment: FYI: TeXmacs doesn't in fact use TeX at all.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yeah but I can export to tex.